# LLVM Pass: to change the function call's argument values

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

part of my project, based on some analysis, I have to change the function call's arguments. I am doing it in the llvm-ir level. something like this,

```
doWork("work",functionBefore)
```

based on my results my llvm-pass should be able to transform the function pointer passed to the function call like this

```
doWork("work",functionAfter)
```

assume both functionBefore and functionAfter have the same return type.

1. Is it possible to change the arguments using llvm pass?
2. Or should i delete the instruction and recreate the one I needed?

Please give some suggestions or directions how to do this ?

llvm ir to the call the function would be something like this-

```
invoke void @_Z7processNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPFvS4_E(%"c lass.std::__cxx11::basic_string"* nonnull %1, void  (%"class.std::__cxx11::basic_string"*)* nonnull   @_Z9functionBNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE) to label %7 unwind label %13
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you just need to find the call instruction and [change one of its operands](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html#a5fa9b8e1842b354f64c1ba6be0a4a17f).

Comment: thankyou.but how to cast function pointers to pass the method setoperands?in our case the pointer to function "functionAfter"?

Comment: I use setOperand() for two things and don't need to cast for either of them... I suspect that if you think you need to cast, then you may have the wrong object and should look for the right object rather than a way to cast.

Comment: Value *New_val = M.getFunction("{refname}");
f->setOperand(1,New_val);
this is how i did .but,while i debug operandlist remains same .what might be the issue?

Comment: 1 might be "work" (and 0 the called function), I don't remember exactly. Try `assert(f->getOperant(1)->getType() == newVal->getType()` to be sure. LLVM uses lots of asserts, it's good to blend in with that style. You can also dump() most values to see them on stderr, e.g. `f->getOperand(1)->dump()`.

Comment: yes 0 is the one.but still can't get this working.

Comment: You have three functions. One is the function being called, another is the old function that is the second argument of the call to the first, the last is the new function pointer. IIRC getOperand() is the first. Don't confuse the first and the third.